# UnboundLocalError from If statement

Tags: python

I keep receiving the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var' referenced before assignment
```

When i try running

```
def func1():
    var = True

def func2():
    if something_random and var == True:
        do stuff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign to a variable in a python function, that variable is local to the function by default.  You *could* make it global:

```
var = False                    # What if func2 was called before func1?

def func1():
    global var
    var = True

def func2():
    global var                 # Not strictly required, but documentary
    something_random = True
    if something_random and var == True:
        print("stuff")

func1()
func2()
```

But global variables are to be avoided where possible.  Why?  Because it can be difficult to follow where they are set, and it means that the functions cannot be reused elsewhere.

So a better solution would be to *encapsulate*:

```
def func1():
    var = True
    return var                 # func1 could be shortened to: return True

def func2(var):
    something_random = True
    if something_random and var == True:
        print("stuff")

result = func1()
func2(result)                  # Some people prefer:  func2(func1())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `var` is defined within the scope of `func1`, and not in the scope of `func2`.  [See this](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) for an explaination of variable scoping in python.